# experiencing 10481 error in paypal

Tags: paypal

Does anyone have an idea what "PaymentAction of Authorization is not allowed with Unilateral and Non-Credentialed authentication" means? I've been getting this error while trying to implement an authorization and capture transaction using paypal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you setting 'SUBJECT'?
If so, the email address in 'SUBJECT' does not belong to an existing PayPal account.

Comment: thanks for mentioning the 'SUBJECT'. I was using my own email address and at the same time my own credentials to do an authorization. I just made the subject empty if I am doing a transaction for my own account and it works.

Comment: I'm also getting this error, but I need to set SUBJECT since I am making API calls on behalf of someone else (by using the Permissions API). SUBJECT = the email address of the person that granted me access. I am sure the SUBJECT is a valid email address (it's a sandbox test account).

Comment: It seems PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION is deprecated when the METHOD is DoExpressCheckoutPayment. Found this in one of the docs of Paypal, they desperately need a single good doc instead of all those bits and pieces they have now.

Comment: Hi! That's not correct fortunately. I'm not sure where you found that, but PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION is most certainly *not* deprecated.

Comment: Been experiencing the error again when using a different paypal account as subject. I was able to use setexpresscheckout api but using the doexpresscheckout, I encountered again the 10481 error though I was granted with api permission but still no luck. Any guess what's wrong?

Answer (score 5):

This happens when SUBJECT emailaddress belongs to registered Paypal account, but authorization  is not permitted by the SUBJECT account.

*Background:*
Let's have account A with known API credentials and account B that belongs to third-party merchant on whose behalf account A is calling the API operation. In order to complete authorization you call DoExpressCheckoutPayment method with A's API credentials and B's email as SUBJECT. This operation will fail unless you allow account A to authorize payments to account B.

*How to enable authorization and capture permission:*
Login to account B, choose tab "My account", click subtab "Profile". There is a column named "Account Information" in which choose "API Access link". Then click on "Add or edit API permissions". Here you can Add New Third Party. Type A account email as "Third Party Permission Username" and check "Authorize and capture your PayPal transactions." Finally save it by clicking "Add". Make sure you have also checked operations necessary prior to authorization like "Use Express Checkout to process payments". Now A can authorize payments to B :)